# Document with ability to change only certain words?

Tags: microsoft-word, document-automation

I am creating an contract template. Instead of highlighting words which needs to be changes each time new contract is created, I'd like to have a fixed and changeable text.

How can I create a Word document where all text will be uneditable except certain words?

Will I be able to jump from word to word via `tab` or similar button?

I was actually searching for this solution on Google, but I was not sure which keywords to use against this search.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you miss is the word "Form" :-)

See if this here helps:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010030746.aspx

Comment: This seems like what I need indeed :). Does forms allow tab navigation from one form to another? For example, I have item1 on page1 and item2 on page2, can I just from one item to another via tab?

Comment: Yes, you can tab through once the document is protected.  The "Protect Document" icon is located on the Developer ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use words Developer tab. If this isn't on the ribbon go to:

1. File,
2. Options,
3. Customize Ribbon,
4. In the right hand box tick the developer checkbox.

In this tab you can create Active X controls such as text entries, Scroll bars and tick boxes.
once your document is created you then need to restrict editing.